# WPF Listbox with touch inertia pulls down entire window

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, touch

I have a full screen WPF application built for a touch monitor, and I have some `Listbox`s  on the main screen.

When I flick the 'Listbox' it scrolls fine, but when it gets to the end of the list, the **entire** application gets pulled down from the top of the screen, can I stop this behavior somehow?

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, that default behaviour of the ListBox (or rather, the ScrollViewer inside the default ListBox template) *is* weird - when I first came across it, I thought it must be a practical joke. In fact, it's really hard to find any documentation about it - but it is briefly mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#touch_and_manipulation):

> The ManipulationBoundaryFeedback event enables applications or components to provide visual feedback when an object hits a boundary. For example, the Window class handles the ManipulationBoundaryFeedback event to cause the window to slightly move when its edge is encountered.

So, a way around it is to handle ManipulationBoundaryFeedback on the ListBox, and set Handled to true:

```
<ListBox ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback">            
  // ...
</ListBox>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(object sender, ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled  = true;
}
```

Comment: This answer helped me in my application. One addition: if you want to disable the boundary feedback for all controls in a window, you should put the ManipulationBoundaryFeedback handle on the first panel of the window, not on the window itself.

Comment: @BrunoV `protected override void OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            //base.OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(e);
        }` inside the `Window` class worked for me.