# C# Winform - How to prevent of moving complete window when moving to end of control with finger on touch screen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm developing full-screen winform application for touch screen.
When I have on the form any control e.g. `listbox`, `webBrowserControl` ... which has visible scrollbar(there are things to scroll) and when I'm moving with finger to the end of the control the complete form is moving up/down depends from moving direction.

The same behaviour also appears when form is not fullscreen.
This appears only by touch screen interaction with application(mouse controlling of app  - all is OK)

When is in control less elements(scrollbar is not visible) the unwanted moving of form is not appearing.

How to disable this unwanted moving of complete form?
thanks for any help

Comment: This is the behavior of the inertia of listboxes in wpf: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505772/wpf-listbox-with-touch-inertia-pulls-down-entire-window

Comment: Thanks for help. 
It helps to start digging deeper and points to this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855130/manipulationboundaryfeedback-does-not-work-in-webbrowser-in-wpf

unfortunately my application is winform not WPF.  The final solution was in registry to change HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch Bouncing to 0

Comment: @Stan, do you mind to share it ? i also have this issue for winform touch screen. thanks

Comment: @chopperfield  Yes you can share it, no problem :) Does it solve your case?

Comment: @Stan lol, i think we are miscommunication. what i mean do you mind to share to code in here? but what i got is you manually setup it on registry .. haha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swipe scroll reveals desktop in fullscreen WinForms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365810/swipe-scroll-reveals-desktop-in-fullscreen-winforms-app)

Comment: The suggested duplicate is a newer question, but it has a code example and the OP posted a solution there.